# Имитация мыши в свернутом окне python

Tags: python, браузер, мышь

Существует ли метод реализации имитации нажатия мыши в свернутом окне на языке python?
Более конкретный(мой) пример:
Имитация поиска определенных запросов и перехода по ссылкам в гугл. 
Обычная имитация мыши через библиотеки типа pyautogui требуют постоянно открытого окна, хочу, чтоб можно было запустить в фоне.
Язык:
python 3.8

Comment: Почему бы не взять selenium, чтобы не мучаться с окнами?

Comment: действительно, существует более тривиальное решение, спасибо.